# What is a trivial and non-trivial heuristic?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I'm currently learning AI and using different tree and graph search algorithms such as DFS, BFS, UCS and A*. I've tried googling but can't find an answer on what's a trivial and non-trivial heuristic?

Does that have any connection as whether the heuristic is admissible?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context in which you found "trivial" and "non-trivial"? These are subjective terms, so there's probably not a canonical answer.

Comment: I found it in a presentation about Informed Search. I've just added the slide witch mentions it.

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I don't recognize the vernacular in that slide. Can you post/link the entirety of the slide deck?